# Vim errors when setting up Plutus Environment

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, error

I'm following [this](https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/Vagrant.html) guide for setting up my Plutus Environment which uses Vagrant & VirtualBox.

At the step:

> In the Vagrantfile directory run & wait for provisioning to finish:
> `vagrant up`

I run into multiple Vim errors-

```
plutus-node-1: Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
plutus-node-1: Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
plutus-node-1: Error detected while processing /home/vagrant/.vimrc:
plutus-node-1: line    1:
plutus-node-1: E488: Trailing characters
plutus-node-1: line    2:
plutus-node-1: E492: Not an editor command: ^M
plutus-node-1: line    3:
plutus-node-1: E116: Invalid arguments for function plug#
plutus-node-1: line    4:
plutus-node-1: E492: Not an editor command: ^M
plutus-node-1: line    5:
plutus-node-1: E488: Trailing characters
plutus-node-1: line    6:
plutus-node-1: E492: Not an editor command: ^M
plutus-node-1: line    7:
plutus-node-1: E492: Not an editor command: ^M
plutus-node-1: line   10:
plutus-node-1: E474: Invalid argument: encoding=utf-8^M
plutus-node-1: line   11:
plutus-node-1: E492: Not an editor command: ^M
plutus-node-1: line   13:
plutus-node-1: E488: Trailing characters: hidden^M
plutus-node-1: line   14:
plutus-node-1: E492: Not an editor command: ^M

Vim: Error reading input, exiting...d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit
plutus-node-1: Vim: Finished.
plutus-node-1: Press ENTER or type command to continueVim: Error reading input, exiting...
plutus-node-1: Vim: Finished.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things. First of why is there a `/home/vagrant/.vimrc` in the first place? Second why does it contain `^M` (that's effectively `\r`), in there? `dos2unix` on `/home/vagrant/.vimrc` should fix that.

Are you using WSL by any chance? I'm unsure how windows line endings could end up in your `.vimrc` otherwise.

Comment: I'm not using WSL, just using Windows 10 command prompt.

To your first two questions I don't really have an answer, I haven't done anything beyond installing Vagrant & Oracle VM and then the followed the steps indicated in that post.

I tried what you suggested but still doesn't work, I'm getting a new error now I believe ?

Error detected while processing function <SNR>8_install[1]..<SNR>8_update_impl[
    plutus-node-1: 114]..<SNR>8_update_vim[4]..<SNR>8_tick:
    plutus-node-1: line   17:
    plutus-node-1: E117: Unknown function: coc#status